# "mysqli_num_rows" struggles with the output of "mysqli_query"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I made a simple Login Form there are some errors in the code I guess.

Everything is working fine but I'm struggling with the MySQL(mysqli) Query part.

But here is my code first:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['acuser']))
{
redirectpage();
}
else
{
if($_POST)
{   
if(isset($_POST['button']) && ($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password']))
{
$db = 'datenbank';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
$selection = mysqli_select_db($connection,$db);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, (htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
$password = md5($password);


if($connection)
{
if($selection)
{
$queryuser = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE Username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryuser);

$checkuser = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($checkuser)
{
$querypass = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password ='$password'";
$resultpass = mysqli_query($connection,$querypass);

$checkpass = mysqli_num_rows($resultpass);
if($checkpass)
{   
$data = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultpass);

$_SESSION["acID"] = $data["Id"];
$_SESSION["acUSERNAME"] = $data["Username"];
$_SESSION["acPASSWORD"] = $data["Password"];
$_SESSION["acEMAIL"] = $data["Email"];
}

// Some else stuff
?>
```

I guess there is something wrong with "mysqli_query()" and "mysqli_num_rows()"!

"Mysqli_num_rows()" can't handle the output of "mysqli_query()" somehow!

Maybe i will find an answer here

Comment: What do you mean by "can't handle the output"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Please check your server's `error.log` file for error messages and post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
```

is the username the same as the password in the database?